# How to make search for places in Google Maps?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, autocompletetextview, google-geocoder

My app is using Google Maps and I want to make searches by address. How can I do this? I would like my search bar to have autocomplete as well.

I'm trying with Geocoder but don't work well. Would the Google Places API be better for this? If yes, I saw that it has a limit of 1000 requests/day. If I go over would I need to pay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My app is using Google Maps and I want to make searches by address.
>   How can I do this? I would like my search bar to have autocomplete as
>   well. 
>   I'm trying with Geocoder but don't work well. Would the Google Places API be better for this?

If you want to search by address and autocomplete search input, you have to use Google Places API https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places

> If yes, I saw that it has a limit of 1000 requests/day. If I go over
>   would I need to pay?

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage
http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2011/07/geo-apis-summer-learning-series-google.html

"Initially your key will offer courtesy quota of 1,000 requests per day. Once you are ready to launch the next great location based app, simply “Enable billing” on the project. You will be prompted to provide credit card details, in order to verify your identity. Once you have done so, your quota will increase to 100,000 requests per day, but the API will remain free to use. Note that you may be charged if you use the same key for other APIs, which you can avoid by creating a separate project for accessing other APIs. "